# VB.NET - Convert Json to Xml using Json.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

Is there any possible way to convert direct url to json into xml as text into one textbox?

Example:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Json1 as string = "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p3uBzBtm"
    Dim jss = New JsonSerializer()
    Dim response2 = jss.Deserialize(Of Object)(Json1)
    textbox1.text = response2
End Sub
```

Sorry for this bad example, I'm newbie in this language.

Comment: What is the expected output (Textbox1's text)?

Comment: Where I want to be the converted xml result.

Comment: Got it. Check out the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Json1 As String = New WebClient().DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=p3uBzBtm")
    Dim str = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(Json1)
    TextBox1.Text = str.OuterXml
End Sub
```

For multiple nodes you will want something like this:

```
Dim Json1 As String = "{ 'root': " & New WebClient().DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ugZrw4d6") & " }"
Dim doc As XmlDocument = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(Json1)
Dim result As String = doc.ChildNodes(0).InnerXml
TextBox1.Text = result
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much! But I see if I want to change the Download String url with another that have multiple lines and nodes it give me error. Can you optimize for this link? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ugZrw4d6

Comment: Since valid xml has only one root node, you have to enclose your JSON in a single object. See updated answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for your amazing helps!

Comment: @qckmini6 Consider accepting this answer. It will help others know that it is a useful solution :)